# VIM: available shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, shortcut

I use many shortcuts for my work in vim.
Other shortcuts are taken by plugins.

Sometimes I would like to add a shortcut for a new command but note afterwards that the shortcut was already taken.

Is there a way to see a list of all available shortcuts in VIM?
(all ctrl-shift-alt shortcuts)

Comment: Try `:help :map` to get a list of commands related to key mappings.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Type `:help index` to see the mappings (shortcuts as you name them) and commands defined by vim itself.

Type `:map` to see the mappings defined by your vimrc and plugins. Type `:verbose map` to know where each mapping was defined.

Also `:help map-listing` to check what's displayed, but you probably already know about it (it's in map.txt help manual).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know the command :map and :verbose map. :h map-listing I've never seen.

Comment: Just a note, I had `vim.o.more = false` in my `init.lua` (neovim). This meant that the log output of `:map` was not scrollable using conventional means. I commented out that setting and it fixed it. (`let &more = v:false` should be the vimL equiv)

Answer (score 18):

If you also want to check which maps or commands are defined by vim itself you can use

```
:help index
```

Comment: nice, thank you.  BTW.. I regret to see that there is no way to see only the NOT-taken ctrl-shift-alt shortcuts.

Answer (score 9):

```
:map //lists all the shortcuts that are assigned.
```

map also takes a key combination as an argument that lists only the shortcuts assigned to this key combination.

To list all the mappings assigned for Ctrl-V:

```
:map <c-v>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this helpful...

http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want a sorted, searchable list of your current mappings to look for unused keys, see my answer at:
[How to search in the Vim mapping listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842063/how-to-search-in-the-vim-mapping-listing/38735360#38735360)

As a starting point, for the keys are not mapped by *default*, see
[`:help map-which-keys`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-which-keys)

You can use `:map < key >` to check a specific mapping. Example: to check Shift-F2, `:map S-<F2>`.

AFAIK, there's no way of getting a list of what's unmapped without writing code to iterate through each possible key combination and check if there is any output from running `:map < key >` for that particular key.