# Display a ordered VIM keyboard mapping

Tags: vim

Is there any away to show a ordered list of **all keyboard mappings** of my current vim environment, like this:

```
a: append
b: back one word
c: ...
.
.
.

---- Ctrl mappings ----
<C-a> (I dont know...)
.
.
.
<C-p> Default mode for CrtlP
...

---- Alt mappings ----
...
```

This will be very useful for me.

Comment: This answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/5391019/32090

Comment: `:help index` seems good, but it's doesn't show my plugins shortcuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:map` and `:verbose map` show you a list of the mappings defined in your session, but they are not ordered like that. AFAIK, Vim doesn't provide such a nice formatting: you'll have to write a custom function for that, I'm afraid.

***edit***

Also, note that `a`, `b` and friends are not "mappings" in the sense that CtrlP's `<C-p>` is a mapping. `:map` won't show them at all.

So your idea, while interesting, is probably not something that can be done with a one liner. You could pull info from `:h index`, add the result of `:map` and try to arrange all of that in an order that makes sense to you but it doesn't seem to be a trivial task. It sounds like a perfect fit for a python/ruby/php script, doesn't it?

***endedit***

Comment: I thought that existed something like that, my idea is use it to help the VIM newcomers. I'll try to write a script to do this later.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a sorted, searchable list of your current mappings in which to look for unused keys, you can do the following:

```
function! s:ShowMaps()
  let old_reg = getreg("a")          " save the current content of register a
  let old_reg_type = getregtype("a") " save the type of the register as well
try
  redir @a                           " redirect output to register a
  " Get the list of all key mappings silently, satisfy "Press ENTER to continue"
  silent map | call feedkeys("\<CR>")    
  redir END                          " end output redirection
  vnew                               " new buffer in vertical window
  put a                              " put content of register
  " Sort on 4th character column which is the key(s)
  %!sort -k1.4,1.4
finally                              " Execute even if exception is raised
  call setreg("a", old_reg, old_reg_type) " restore register a
endtry
endfunction
com! ShowMaps call s:ShowMaps()      " Enable :ShowMaps to call the function

nnoremap \m :ShowMaps<CR>            " Map keys to call the function
```

This is a robust function to create a vertical split with the sorted output of `:maps`. I put it in my `vimrc`.

The last line maps the two keys <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> to call the function, change this as you wish.

Note: As @romainl mentions, this will will not include commands like <kbd>i</kbd> to insert text

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13208001)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've now included the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also user the [FZF Plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) which gives you the `:Maps` command which brings up the same information as `:verbose map` but in a pop up window that's fuzzy searchable. Its essentially the same as Tom Hales answer but an fzf version. I've mapped it to `<leader>F1`.