# How to search in the Vim mapping listing?

Tags: vim

Using `:map` provides a list of all mappings in Vim. But, I am unable to search through the list. I am surprised to see it being opened in a different type of window unlike usual Vim help files. Is there a way to have it available in the usual form?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't be surprised. `:map` is not related *at all* with `:help` so there's no reason whatsoever to expect it to work like `:help`.

You can give `:map` an argument to narrow-down the listing:

```
:map ,
```

With the right values for `wildmenu` and/or `wildmode`, you can tab-complete `:map`:

```
:map ,<Tab>
```

You can also list the current mappings with `<C-d>`:

```
:map <C-d>
```

You can also use the mode-specific variants of `:map` to get a more manageable list:

```
:imap ,
:nmap ,
:xmap ,
and so on…
```

But keep in mind that `:map` only lists custom mappings (made by you or your plugins). If you want a list of default mappings, check out `:help index`.

--- EDIT ---

So, a recent upvote reminded me of this old answer and it turns out that a new command, `:help :filter` has been added in the mean time to help with that kind of use case.

You would use it like this to only list your insert mode mapping that use `:help pumvisible()`:

```
:filter pumvisible imap
```

Not technically a search, mind you, but a pretty useful addition nonetheless.

Answer (score 22):

Vim uses its internal pager to display the output of `:map`, which has pretty limited functionalities (see `:h pager` for more info).

If you want to access the output of `:map` in a normal vim buffer, you could use `:redir` :

```
:redir @a>    " redirect output to register a
:map
:redir END
:put a        " paste the output of :map in the current buffer
```

Note that you can redirect to a file, to a variable, etc... See `:h redir` for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of map works and the bit on pointer to redir. But I think, I should accept the previous answer as its actually the one thats specific to the actual question.

Comment: i am too thinking around `:redir`. +1

Comment: It is much more handy to use custom Redir function which opens separate scratch window (like `less`) as romainl described here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49083560/1455694

Answer (score 8):

Here's a robust function to create a searchable vertical split with the sorted output of `:maps`

```
function! s:ShowMaps()
  let old_reg = getreg("a")          " save the current content of register a
  let old_reg_type = getregtype("a") " save the type of the register as well
try
  redir @a                           " redirect output to register a
  " Get the list of all key mappings silently, satisfy "Press ENTER to continue"
  silent map | call feedkeys("\<CR>")    
  redir END                          " end output redirection
  vnew                               " new buffer in vertical window
  put a                              " put content of register
  " Sort on 4th character column which is the key(s)
  %!sort -k1.4,1.4
finally                              " Execute even if exception is raised
  call setreg("a", old_reg, old_reg_type) " restore register a
endtry
endfunction
com! ShowMaps call s:ShowMaps()      " Enable :ShowMaps to call the function

nnoremap \m :ShowMaps<CR>            " Map keys to call the function
```

The last line maps the two keys <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> to call the function, change this as you wish.

Comment: But the sort isn't working so well... they're all jumbled up; maybe because of OS X differences? I changed to `sort --key=1,14`.

Comment: Does one need the assignment to the `@a` at all? Why cannot one just `put` the value of `silent map | ...` into the new buffer?

Comment: Thank you! I am getting the 'No write since last change (add ! to override)' warning. Is there a way to avoid this by opening as a read only buffer or something?

Answer (score 6):

For neovim, [telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) has mapping list and search capability out of the box: `builtin.keymaps`.

Comment: I imagine this answer could be improved by giving some more context for those who don't know what telescope is.  I'd never used it but now I have a starting point.

For others: I have telescope installed via packer (described in the link you shared) then ran :Telescope, typed keymaps, hit enter, and then was able to find the keymaps I was interested in by typing a bit of what I expected to find.

Here's a sample for anyone else struggling, if it helps: https://asciinema.org/a/g9YF0I3tw5nyn4U0l2NIiqRTR

I don't understand how to search, obviously, but docs can get me the rest of the way.